# Rewrite an HTTP request for Vuforia

Tags: php, http, curl, httprequest, vuforia

Can anybody help me to rewrite the following request in curl or anything similar which is available in php 5.6? I'm new with http request in PHP and I'm not able to use the HttpRequest class cause it can't be found on the server. Other suggestions are welcome too. Maybe there is already a library?

```
 $path = "content/images/calendarmotiv/";
 $fail = true;


                $tmp = $_FILES['imagetarget']['tmp_name'];
                $name = basename($_FILES['imagetarget']['name']);
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name))
                {

                    // http request body
                    $now = new DateTime('NOW');
                    $body = json_encode(array(
                        "name" => $name,
                        "width" => 1024.0,
                        "image_url" => base64_encode($path.$name),
                        "active_flag" => 1,
                        "application_metadata_url" => base64_encode($_POST["metadata"]))
                        );

                    $http_verb = "POST";
                    $content_md5 = md5($body);
                    $content_type = "application/json";
                    $date = str_replace("+0000", "GMT", $now->format(DateTime::RFC1123));
                    $request_path = "<a href='https://vws.vuforia.com/targets'> https://vws.vuforia.com/targets</a>";

                    // auth string for header
                    $string_to_sign = $http_verb . "\n" . $content_md5 . "\n" . $content_type . "\n" . $date . "\n" . $request_path;
                    $secret_key = "mykey";
                    $signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $string_to_sign, $secret_key);
                    $authstring = "VWS " . $secret_key . ":" . $signature;

                    // the request
                    $request = new HttpRequest($request_path, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
                    $request->setContentType($content_type);
                    $request->setBody($body);
                    $request->addHeaders(array(
                        "Date" => $date,
                        "Authorization" => $authstring));

                    $request->send();

                    echo $request->getRequestMessage();
                    echo $request->getResponseMessage();
                }
```

Comment: Assuming built with cURL I think HTTP extension should work fine. Thing that jumps out at me is the `$request_path` value being HTML markup.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the `$request_path` probably should not be a HTML markup. I just copied the code from [link](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/general-discussion/help-me-use-vws-api-php) because it is exactly what I need. But I could not get this to run.

Comment: I've found a [library](https://github.com/jacobtabak/curl-vuforia-client/blob/master/VuforiaClient.php) which I could use for this case, but my only response from Vuforia is a **"result_code":"BadImage"** and a "transaction_id" no matter which image I upload and a target is not created. I've got no idea how to debug this without further information. Anyone has seen that too?

Comment: Show the code with that new library perhaps? It sounds as if you got further, at least connecting and not getting say an auth error. How is the image *uploaded*? As a base64 encoded string or a multipart/form-data post?

Comment: I see they have a PHP SDK and docs. You should be able to follow a working code example I'd think. https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-the-Vuforia-Web-Services-API

Comment: Thank you for the right hint! It was a failure in my image base64 conversion I did not see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a Vuforia client class in PHP for basic operations with Vuforia target database:

https://github.com/FionNoir/VuforiaClient